# Can I get bash to ignore leading `:` when it's present?

Tags: bash

Often, if I'm working in bash (on macOS), I'm also working in (Mac)Vim, switching between the two. A common mistake I make after switching from Vim to Terminal is to include a leading colon before the command. I'll `:cd /path/to/project/dir/` in Vim and then switch to Terminal and type the exact same thing, except, of course, I shouldn't start with a colon there.

So, I don't know of any time when a bash command *should* begin with a colon, and every time *I* do it I don't mean to. So, is there a way to get bash to completely ignore the colon if it's the first character in a command, and interpret `:cd ...` as `cd ...`?

Comment: Do you want that for *every* command or just the `cd` command?

Comment: I suppose every command. The `cd` was an example, but sometimes, my muscle memory will begin a Terminal command with `:`, and I'll type `:mkdir ...`. I don't think there's ever an time when a valid terminal command could begin with a colon, right?

Comment: @Chuck: `:` is a valid command http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16

Comment: @Chuck oh dear. A colon is perfectly valid in file names too (and most commands are file names). And I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but so are things like spaces, tabs, even newlines and various other possibly totally unprintable characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bash(1)` will call the `command_not_found_handle()` function if defined and the command to be executed is not found. If you are not already using this feature (such as with the command-not-found package on Ubuntu), you could use it to strip off the colon and try again:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    if [[ "${1:0:1}" != : ]]; then
        printf "%s: %s: command not found\n" "$0" "$1" >&2
        return 127
    else
        "${1/#:}" "${@:2}"
    fi
}
```

Put that function into your `.bashrc`. Then, when a command that starts with a colon is not found, it will strip the colon off the front and try again.

Edit: I'll explain a bit further since there are some uncommon expansions here.

First of all, as noted in the comments, `command_not_found_handle` is a bash 4 feature. Bash 4 was released in Feb 2009. The `command_not_found_handle` function is called with arguments that is the command not found and that command's arguments. i.e. `$1` is the command not found and `$2` onwards are the arguments to the command that was not found. This is described under *COMMAND EXECUTION* in the man page.

`"${1:0:1}"` is an expansion which takes a substring from `$1`, from position 0 of length 1. That is, it extracts the first character from `$1`, where `$1` is the command that was not found. This is documented under *Parameter Expansion* in the man page as `${parameter:offset:length}`.

If the first character of `$1` is not a colon, we print an error and return with an exit value of 127. 127 is the exit code bash uses when it does not find the command to execute as documented under *COMMAND EXECUTION* in the man page.

`"${1/#:}"` expands to `$1` with any leading colon stripped off. If there is no colon at the start, it is equivalent to a plain `$1`, but we know it starts with a colon anyway due to the branch of the condition we are in. This expansion is documented under *Parameter Expansion* in the man page in the `${parameter/pattern/string}` section.

`"${@:2}"` expands to the positional parameters from the second onwards. This expansion is documented under *Parameter Expansion* in the man page in the `${parameter:offset}` section, as a special case for arrays and `@`. That is, instead of extracting a substring, it expands to elements of the array.

The end result is that if a command not found is run and it has a leading colon, we strip off the colon to form a new command and pass the original arguments to the new command. This will end up working recursively as if the second attempt to run a command is not found, `command_not_found_handle()` will be executed again. This means you could run `:::mkdir` and it will still end up running `mkdir`.

Comment: It sounds good in theory, but I haven't gotten to work in practice. I copied and pasted your code (after it didn't work when I typed it manually in) and still got `-bash: :cd: command not found` in response to `:cd`. I posted the results of a test in terminal on [gist](https://gist.github.com/chivalry/d887d5c00c62e1695c4cacf66f984930), if it helps. I'll investigate `command_not_found_handle` and see if I can figure it out. I admit, the bash code is above my head, but should be fun to figure out. :)

Comment: Turns out that `command_not_found_handle` was [introduced in bash 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555816/command-not-found-handler-not-working-in-mac) and `bash --version` reveals that I'm using version 3.2.57. Apparently I can upgrade with Homebrew, but I'm a bit hesitant to do so. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Upgrading is fine. `brew` installs to `/usr/local`; it doesn't touch `/bin/bash`. Using `/usr/local/bin/bash` (or whatever) that is version 4 won't affect any system scripts that are being executed with `/bin/sh` anyway. As far as I know, there are no differences (in terms of POSIX compliance) between version 3.2 and version 4.x.

Comment: @camh Thanks so much for the detailed explanation of the function syntax.

Comment: @chepner, I've already used Homebrew to install bash 4, and will soon make it my default shell, at least to try it out and make sure nothing broke.